# Recursive function returns null while variable prints value inside function

Tags: php

So, I've written a code to find all possible paths for M x N matrix

```
function printRobotPaths($path,$m,$n,$x,$y) {
        if (($x == $m-1) && ($y == $n-1)) {
            return $path;
        }
        if ($x == $m-1) {
            return printRobotPaths($path.'D',$m,$n,$x,$y+1);
        }
        if ($y == $n-1) {
            return printRobotPaths($path.'R',$m,$n,$x+1,$y);
        }
        printRobotPaths($path.'D',$m,$n,$x,$y+1);
        printRobotPaths($path.'R',$m,$n,$x+1,$y);
    }
$m = 3;
$n = 3;
$x = 0;
$y = 0;


$data = array(
    array(1,2,3),
    array(4,5,6),
    array(7,8,9)
);

$path = printRobotPaths('',$m,$n,0,0);
var_dump($path);
```

but the problem is when I'm returning $path then it var_dump() result is NULL but for same if I just print $path inside the function it will print correct answer

I wanted to return all possible 6 ways from it.

Comment: `printRobotPaths(...)` doesn't return anything

Comment: if (($x == $m-1) && ($y == $n-1)) {
            return $path;
        }

Comment: I'm confused what is supposed to be returned if none of the `if` statements are true. Which of the *two* recursive calls at the end do you expect to return…?

Comment: when I echo $path.' - ' in first if condition it prints : "DDRR - DRDR - DRRD - RDDR - RDRD - RRDD " I want to return this string but don't know how @deceze